# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < на WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, site

Был уже готовый сайт на WordPress с конструктором страниц и несколькими плагинами.
Немножко изменил у себя на локальном сервере, залил на хостинг и тут появилась ошибка. Конструктор страниц стал так же не работать(плагин есть и активирован но в режиме редактирования конструктора нет). Конструктор страниц SiteOrigin(если это нужно).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка указывает сюда:
[image: Вот ошибка в консоли]

В коде на самом деле таких лишних тегов нет:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var logoSlider = $("#lcs_logo_carousel_slider");
                logoSlider.owlCarousel({
                    loop:true,
                    autoWidth:false,
                    responsiveClass:true,
                    dots:<?= $lcsPagiTrueFalse; ?>,
                    autoplay:<?= $lcsAutoPlayRun; ?>,
                    autoplayTimeout: <?= (!empty($slider_speed)) ? intval($slider_speed) : 4000; ?>,
                    autoplayHoverPause: false,
                    dotData:true,
                    dotsEach:true,
                    slideBy:1,
                    rtl:<?= is_rtl() ? 'true': 'false'; ?>,
                    nav:<?=( !empty( $lcsDisplayNavArr) && 'yes' == $lcsDisplayNavArr ) ? 'true':'false'; ?>,
                    navText:['‹','›'],
                    smartSpeed: 1000, // it smooths the transition
                    responsive:{
                        0 : {

                            items:2
                        },
                        500: {
                            items:3
                        },
                        600 : {
                            items:3
                        },
                        768:{
                            items:4
                        },
                        1199:{
                            items:<?= intval($lcsLogoItems); ?>
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Кеширующие плагины есть? Сбрасывали кеш?

Comment: У вас скрипт вставлен прямо в страницу. Это очень плохая практика. Надо выносить в отдельный файл и запускать как положено, через `wp_enqueue_script()`. Но даже на странице можно использовать. Я полагаю, что вы воткнули скрипт прямо в текстовый блок. так нельзя. У всех page builders есть специальные блоки для html и js.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev если вы про кеш браузера - то да, пробовал.

Comment: @KAGGDesign сейчас посмотрю и отпишусь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена! При переносе сайта если появляются какие то ошибки похожие на этот, то вы первом делом должны проверить всё ли нормально перенеслась? Попробовал перенесети на другой хостинг с помощью плагина Duplicator и всё получилось. Надеюсь хоть кому-то моя практика поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы копировали скрипт, то редактор WordPress мог заменить крытые символы переноса строки на

Проверьте ваш код в простом текстовом редакторе (Notepad++ или Sublime)